# Is it possible to get top 10 from ktable\kstream?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic with a `String` key which is a signal type and `Signal` value which is a class like this

```
public clas Signal {
  public final int deviceId;
  public final int value;
  ...
}
```

Each device can send signal values which raise or fall with time without a pattern.

Is it possible to get top 10 devices with max signal `value` at all period of time by each type (key of the topic) as a `KTable<String,Signal>`? Would it helped if all signal values were raising?

Topic structure can be changed if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do with Kafka Streams for the case when values are always raising, for example. It is needed to create own `Top10` aggregate, which stores top 10 and updates it on `add` call:

```java
    final var builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    final var topTable = builder
        .table(
            SignalChange.TOPIC_NAME,
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new SignalChange.Serde())
        ).toStream()
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(
            () -> new Top10(),
            (k, v, top10) -> top10.add(v),
            Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new Top10.Serde())
        );
```

`topTable` can then be joined with any stream requesting for the top.

Comment: Would be useful to see your `SignalChange` and `Top10` class and its serde

Comment: Also, why do values always need to be raising? You can scan all 10 existing values and do insertion-sort for your collection before serializing the output record. If there are any less than the min value in that 10, you'd just ignore it. Any less than or equal to the max, you remove the min